# PHP Session Information Not Being Stored

Tags: php, session

I am trying to make a very simple website, where you can go to the main page and log in, of which the code is here **example.org/login/index.php:**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $warning = $_GET['warning'];
    $nolog = $_GET['nolog'];
    $username = "Welcome, please log in";
    if ($warning) {
        $username = "Wrong Username/Password Combination";
    }
    if ($nolog) {
        $username = "Page inaccessible: Login required";
    }
    if ($logout) {
        $username = "Thank you for your session";
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <div class="center">
        <span class="warning"><?= $username ?></span>
        <form action="submit.php" method="post">
            <span class="formField">Username:</span><br>
            <input type="text" name="user" class="field">
            <br>
            <span class="formField">Password:</span><br>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="field">
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="field">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The submit page looks like this (when I get this to work I won't have the username and password hard coded like this, it's just to be concise for now) **example.org/login/submit.php**:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $username = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if ($username == "admin" && $password == "12345") {
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
        header("Location: http://www.example.org/welcome/");
        die();
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = FALSE;
        header("Location: http://www.example.org/login/index.php?warning=true");
        die();
    }
?>
```

And the welcome page looks like this **example.org/welcome/index.php**:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] == FALSE){
        unset($_SESSION);
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: http://www.example.org/login/index.php?nolog=true");
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    Hi
</body>
</html>
```

I know this is a lot of code, but when I try running it the first time around the welcome page returns an error saying that it is inaccessible, and sends me back to the login page, but the second time around it seems to work fine and logs me in. Can anyone understand why that would be?

**EDIT:**

After looking more into it, I discovered that the problem ONLY exists in Google Chrome and Firefox, but does not exist in other browsers such as Internet Explorer or Apple Safari. This now goes into the rendering engine of the browsers. Does anyone perhaps know of another way that I can use session ID's that might bypass this whole issue on all browsers, perhaps another way of validating a user?

Comment: This code works provided this is a real spot: `header("Location: http://www.example.org/welcome/");` Should it maybe be: `header("Location: http://www.example.org/welcome.php");`?

Comment: Hmmm, well when I try your code, it worked for me. Set all the proper sessions and such and forwarded me to the right spot....

Comment: @Rasclatt Sorry for deleting my previous comment, but I would rather not keep my username/password info up. I changed the link to http://www.example.org/welcome/index.php, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you label above in your code sample what each page is named per code block? Like **welcome/index.php:** ect

Comment: I will try it. You can delete it again..

Comment: I just tried it. It seemed to work for me. I put in the username and password and it went to a boat-load of buttons called "bunk"

Comment: For some reason, on every browser I am trying on many machines all fail the first time I try to log in, but the second time it works. Did it work your first time? If so, what browser were you using?

Comment: Works the first time. I am using Safari on a Mac.

Comment: The good thing is that we have narrowed my issue. Thank you. I spoke with someone else who tried it on Internet Explorer on Windows 7 and it worked there. So for some reason, on both mobile and desktop versions of Chrome and Firefox and smaller browsers it isn't working, but on other browsers such as Safari and IE (ironically) it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pay attention to the names of the files that I mentioned, I was saying that I was directing my browser to example.org/login/submit.php and then forwarding that to www.example.org/welcome/index.php.

In Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox, they care about the difference between having a www before the website or not, whereas in Internet Explorer and Safari they do not care about the difference. On my server the website www.example.org and example.org are mirrors of each other (this is a separate security issue) and therefore Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox will treat them differently and give them different $_SERVER global variables, whereas Internet Explorer and Safari don't care about that difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following

```
define('BASE_URL', 'http://www.example.org/');

if ($username == "admin" && $password == "12345") {
   $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
   header("Location:".BASE_URL."welcome.php");
   exit();
} else {
   header("Location:".BASE_URL."index.php");
   exit();
}
```

Add the following in the begining of welcome page

```
session_start();    
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
   header("Location:".BASE_URL."index.php");
   exit();
}
```

Comment: Why should defining the base URL make a difference? As for the way you reworked the setting the loggedin variable to be true or nothing, that method didn't help, but thanks anyway